# Is the longitudinal extremity of an obstacle limitation surface based on the threshold or the displaced threshold?

Tags: runways, approach, icao-sarps, morocco

In a case where a displaced threshold (DTHR) is present, should the longitudinal extremity of the obstacle limitation surfaces (for example, the conical surfaces) be counted from the threshold (THR) or from the DTHR (case of Moroccan airport)?

Comment: Hello Yassine Oubaslam, welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com! I added a tag 'ICAO' to your question as I assume the jurisdiction you are asking about does not deviate from the ICAO recommendations in the context of this question. I you want to have an answer specific for your country, please add that country to the tag-list.

Comment: Hello Yassine, thank you for adding the country. I've converted it to a tag (the Morocco tag did not exist yet, congratulations on first Morocco question!). I think the Morocco aviation laws are quite close the ICAO standards and recommendations, so I left the ICAO tags as well. I think Annex 14 describes the obstacle limitation surface, you could have a look there and see whether the DTHR is mentioned in the relevant section.